# PowerShell CSV Import AD Query Username from Mailaddress

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV file with mail addresses and various other stuff in it and I try to get the AD accounts from it.

CSV looks like this:

```
TestUserMail;AccountNumber;TestDisplayName
user.surname@domain.com;1;
user.surname@domain.com;2;
user.surname@domain.com;3;
```

Code looks like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\test.csv' -delimiter ";" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.TestDisplayName = Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq '$_.TestUserName'} |
                         Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    $_
} | Format-Table
```

The issue is that somehow it seems that it cannot do the ad query with the `$_.TestUserName` variable. The result is always that it is empty. If I put a mailadress directly into the script it works just fine.

Does anyone have a idea whats going wrong of any other way how to pull this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a mistake in a filter. There should be an $_.TestUserMail instead of TestUserName.
Second, your expression in a single quotes is not expanded.
this works.

```
 Import-Csv -Path 'C:\tmp\test.csv' -delimiter ";" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.TestDisplayName = get-aduser -filter "mail -eq '$($_.TestUserMail)'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
 $_ } | Format-Table
```

Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps

Comment: Hello Sergius, thank you very much the mistake was correct i saw it after read your comments. Your tip did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `$_` automatic variable wrong. Inside the loop, `$_` is one object taken from the CSV file with a property 'TestUserMail'

Something like this should work

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\test.csv' -Delimiter ";" | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -eq '$_.TestUserMail'" -Properties mail, Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # if we found a user with that email address, output the users Name as object
    # so Format-Table will provide a header.
    if ($user) { $user | Select-Object Name }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is situated in your variable expansion.

```
mail -eq '$_.TestUserName'
```

has 3 issues:

- you use single quotes, so there is *no* variable expansion done at all
- $_ is expanded, and not $_.TestUserName.  You need to enclose them in $()
- the column name is TestUserMail

The correct syntax would be:

```
mail -eq "$($_.TestUserMail)"
```